# ASP.NET MVC 5 App using OWIN with Facebook log-in throwing reference error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wif, owin

I"m following along with this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

I'm attempting to log-in using Facebook. I copied this code almost verbatim:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Forms;
using Owin;

namespace WineNight
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseSignInCookies();

            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
               appId: "000000000000000",
               appSecret: "000000000000000");

            app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error when I call `UseSignInCookies`:

`Owin.IAppBuilder` does not contain a definition for `UseSignInCookies` and no extension method `UseSignInCookies` accepting a first argument of type `Owin.IAppBuilder` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
C:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WineNight\WineNight\App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs
```

I installed the beta package for `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Forms`, but I'm still getting this error. Where does this extension method reside?

Comment: Does it work if you use built in login system?

Comment: I haven't attempted, I'm simply trying to get Facebook integration working with an MVC application, but I'm unclear where `UseSignInCookies` is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the app.UseExternalSignInCookie() extension method.